# Lookup in excel with no VBA

Tags: excel, lookup

I am trying to compose an excel spread sheet on which there would be two sheets.

One sheet (sheet2) with a list of names in one column and next to each name a number.

I would then this column of names as a list for a drop down list in another sheet (sheet).

What I am trying to work out is when I select a name on the drop down list, the number next to the name on sheet2 will be displayed on the cell next to the drop down list.

I am trying to use lookup but it does not seem to work, I guess I am using it wrong.

This is the formula I am using which is placed on the cell next to the drop down list and the drop down list is on A1 in Sheet1.

=LOOKUP(A1,{+Sheet2!A2:A7,"d";+Sheet2!B2:B7})

Sheet2!A2:A7 is the list of names
Sheet2!B2:B7 is the list of respective values for each name.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a job for `VLOOKUP()`

Comment: `LOOKUP` is deprecated. It also only works on sorted data. See Tim's suggestion.

Comment: General excel question like this would be better directed to http://www.superuser.com in the future.

Comment: Tim and A. Webb: Thanks you were right!

Answer (score 2):

`=vlookup(A1,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$7,2,0)` should return the proper value, as Tim WIlliams suggested.